# Get Object API name of any Lookup field

Tags: apex, custom-object, lookup, metadata-api, sobject

I have requirement where I need the object name of any lookup field on any object.
for fetching lookup field I am using Schema class

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.CustomOpportunity__c.fields.CustomTask__c;

for(Schema.SObjectType reference : f.getReferenceTo()) {
    System.debug('Lookup reference object name: ' + reference.getDescribe().getName());
    System.debug('Lookup reference object label: ' + reference.getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

This gives me the name and API name of the lookup object but I want to make it for any object so I changed above code to below

```
String objectName = 'CustomOpportunity__c';
String fieldName =  'CustomTask__c';
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = 
Schema.sObjectType.objectName.fields.fieldName;

for(Schema.SObjectType reference : f.getReferenceTo()) {
    System.debug('Lookup reference object name: ' + reference.getDescribe().getName());
    System.debug('Lookup reference object label: ' + reference.getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

I know that It will throw an error saying Schema.SObjectType.objectName.fields does not exist or something.

I want to make this function generic function where I can pass the objectName and lookup fieldName and it returns me the Lookup object API name and Label Name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) method that accepts String as API name of object and then use [`getMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe) method to get map of `SObjectFields`

```
String objectName = 'Opportunity';
String fieldName =  'AccountId';
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
    .get(objectName)
    .getDescribe()
    .fields
    .getMap()
    .get(fieldName)
    .getDescribe();

for(Schema.SObjectType reference : f.getReferenceTo()) {
    System.debug('Lookup reference object name: ' + reference.getDescribe().getName());
    System.debug('Lookup reference object label: ' + reference.getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without [Schema.getGlobalDescribe()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm), since [Schema.getGlobalDescribe()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) is expensive. I've taken the other poster's code and tweaked it a bit to remove the Schema.getGlobalDescribe.

```
String objectName = 'Opportunity';
String fieldName = 'AccountId';
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = ((SObject) Type.forName('Schema', objectName)
    .newInstance())
  .getSObjectType()
  .getDescribe()
  .fields
  .getMap()
  .get(fieldName)
  .getDescribe();

for (Schema.SObjectType reference : f.getReferenceTo()) {
  System.debug(
    'Lookup reference object name: ' + reference.getDescribe().getName()
  );
  System.debug(
    'Lookup reference object label: ' + reference.getDescribe().getLabel()
  );
}
```

Comment: FYI `Schema` is the default namespace and can be omitted for the most part.